# Quando eu passo um valor do javascript pro php ele se modifica

Tags: php, javascript, base64

Eu tenho uma imagem convertida em base64 ,quando eu envio essa string do javascript pro php ele modifica essa string.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Oi, Adolfo!

Como estás fazendo essa conversão no JS?
Algo tipo assim? Essa abaixo mostra no console 3 resultados para o texto "Olá Mundo!": original, Base64 e Decodificada.

```js
   const str = "Olá mundo!";
   const base64 = btoa(str);
   const decode = atob(base64);
   console.log("Original: " + str);
   console.log("Base64: " + base64);
   console.log("Decodificada: " + decode);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt_br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Olá mundo!</title>
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <h1>Olá mundo!</h1>
      
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Se tu mandar esse base64 para o PHP o resultado muda?
Tipo assim:

```html
<?php
   $str = 'tua base64 string aqui';
   echo base64_decode(urldecode($str));
?>
```